# how to use a loop for specific time in java?

Tags: java, applet

what I want to do is execute loop for a particular amount of time like 10 seconds and during that time I want to calculate number of times mouse is clicked in applet window.

something like this

```
for(10 seconds)
{
    a=getClickCount()
}

texfield.setText(+a);
```

the problem I am facing is this that the value of count starts increasing when I stop clicking and then it starts increasing second by second , till now I have been using
nanoTime method .

Answer (score 0):

If I were you I would Implement a [MouseListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html).

Set a flag to symbolize the start of counting and store the current time stamp, then periodically check the current time and compare the seconds of the current time with the time stamp you have saved. Each successful click within the alotted time can increment a integer value. Then you just call getClickCount() from the MouseListener object.

Once the current time is 10s later than the stored time, set the flag to false.

Comment: I have already implemented MouseListener and the above code has been in "public void mouseClicked" tag

Comment: Have you tried using the time stamp and boolean flag method that I suggested?

Answer (score 0):

you can use a thread ? like this:

```
static final int SLEEP_MILLIS = 1000;//1 sec

Thread counter = new Thread("count click thread") {

    public void run() {
        int nbMillis = 10000; //10sec
        do {
            a = getClickCount();
            refreshView();
            Thread.sleep(SLEEP_MILLIS);
            nbMillis -= SLEEP_MILLIS;
        } while(nbSec>0);
    }
};

counter.start();
```

refreshView() contains the code to edit the text.
SLEEP_MILLIS contains the refresh time interval.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to implement this is using a [Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html) and a MouseListener (as Chris Cooney mentioned).

When you want to start counting 10 seconds - set the timer and register the listener to it's event.
Turn on the `boolean` that says you should count clicks.
And in your MouseListener start counting as long as the `boolean` flag is set to `true`.

Once the Timer's event activates your listener - you can turn off the `boolean` flag and get the actual count of clicks.